# Android Studio: Calling multiple Canvas in ScrollView to display 1 drawing (canvas) after another

Tags: java, android, canvas, scrollview

I'm writing a code for a school project where one has to load a data file (CSV file, text file, etc) and from the obtained data, the app will pass the data to a custom draw View and the onDraw method will draw/plot a graph based on the data.

My goal is for the app to display 2 graphs, one after the other (stacked). The first set of data is loaded and the 1st graph is drawn. The loaded data is then used for a different calculation in a different method. The custom draw View is then called again with the new data to draw the 2nd graph.

When I run the app, both charts are drawn but because the x and y-axis' of the graph are coded to be drawn at certain fixed pixels, the 2nd graph is drawn over the first one and therefore only the 2nd graph is visible.

Is there any way I can draw the 2 graphs so that it does not overlap and instead appears to be stacked in ScrollView?

My code is shown below but I've gotten rid of calculations that I think aren't very important. Any help and pointers would be very much appreciated!

MainActivity.java:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(......) {
        super.onActivityResult(......);
        switch (1) {
            case 1:
                Graph graph = this.findViewById(R.id.graph1);
                graph.setData(data); // the loaded data is passed to Graph View
                Graph drawGraph2 = this.findViewById(R.id.graph2);
                graph2.setData(this.newCalculate(data));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Graph.java

```java
    public  class Graph extends View {
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private final int zero = 700; // mark the 0 line of graph at 700 pixels


    public void setData(data){   
        ......
    }

    public Graph(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
    }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        plotUnit(canvas);    // plot points on graph

        axisLabel(canvas);    // label axis

        axisLine(canvas);     // draw axis

        xyAxisMarker(canvas);    // mark axis
    }

    private void plotUnit(Canvas canvas) {
        ......
        // Due to data having negative values, the graph is inverted and the 0 starts
        // of the graph is defined at 700 pixels （private final int zero)
    }

    private void axisLabel(Canvas canvas) {
        ......
    }

    private void axisLine(Canvas canvas, int inset) {
        ......
    }

    private void xyAxisMarker(Canvas canvas) {
        ......
    }
```

#### Update

activity_main.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/loadbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Open Data File" />

                <firstapp.drawtwograph.Graph
                    android:id="@+id/graph1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <firstapp.drawtwograph.Graph
                    android:id="@+id/graph2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your XML layout. The issue might be there.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu I've edited the post and added my XML layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two views' heights match parent height inside of a `LinearLayout` **with vertical orientation**. It is not possible because heights of these views must be equal to the parent height but at the same time, they must be ordered one after the other resulting in double of parent's height.

If you imagine parent's height as `10dp` then each of the `Graph` views must be 10dp as well which means parent's height must be `20dp`, not `10dp`. That is going to cycle forever so the Android does a simple thing: views that are going below the first child view with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` will have height `0dp` or if their height is fixed they will be drawn outside of the layout and will not be visible.

#### Example

[image: Example of the issue]

*Screenshot from Design tab of layout editor in Android Studio IDE.*

Here you can see:

- red view as a parent linear layout;
- purple view as a first child with height matching it's parent height;
- outlined view that is drawn outside of the layout because it is pushed out by the first child with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`;
- there is one more view that is crushed to 0 height and thus not visible. You can see it down in the XML code.

XML code of this sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- this view's height is a problem -->
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- height is not fixed, then it will be 0 -->
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" <!-- height is fixed, it is outlined outside of a layout -->
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### How to fix the issue?

1. Set fixed height. As a test try to define a fixed height, e.g. `100dp`;
2. Redesign your layout. Use `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout` to position views relative to each other so that they are always visible no matter what the screen size, ratio, density is.

#### Example of how to fix

I personally prefer `ConstraintLayout` as it is very powerful in terms of positioning and adaptation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open Data File"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <firstapp.drawtwograph.Graph
        android:id="@+id/graph1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/graph2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loadbutton" />

    <firstapp.drawtwograph.Graph
        android:id="@+id/graph2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/graph1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result is (I used two buttons instead of Graph views):

[image: Example of a solution]

*Hints:*

- *If you want to use `ScrollView` then setting fixed height or defining height at runtime will be required.*
- *Get rid of `private final int zero = 700; // mark the 0 line of graph at 700 pixels`. Do not use pixel values directly as it will lead to error-prone UI. It will be the case of "work on my phone, does not work the other". Use view's height as the 0 line.*